# how to compare entire data of each table between two databases and both databases has different architecture .

Tags: sybase

We came across a situation where we need to compare the data between two databases and both databases have different architecture ( new and old - means table names and field names on one database is different than other ) .

We cannot use any third party tool .Also the data is in huge volume so Excel would not be the good option.

Need help ...

Thanks

Comment: Which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version?  Do you by any chance have Sybase's Replication Server (SRS) (v15.7.1 or v16) in house?  If so, you could use the Data Assurance product that comes bundled with SRS.

Comment: I don't believe you can compare datasets of different structure effectively. You can run aggregates that you know must be the same, such as general ledger amounts etc. Maybe counts. Other than that it's very vague. An example here would be helpful.